# Custom data-id wp_enqueue_script

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script

I need to insert something like this in wordpress:

```
<script id="customID" data-name="customDataName" src="https://url.com/main.js"></script>
```

I am using wp_enqueue_script but I can not find how to add an id and a data-name to the script

Comment: You can't add attributes directly with `wp_enqueue_script()`. There's workarounds, but could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve, it could influence the answer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The script main.js gets the data-name to open a chat window custom for that data-name. I was using add_action('wp_footer', 'myScript',50); but I see that it is not the proper way to use it.

Comment: Is the script itself yours, or a 3rd party's?

Comment: It is mine, but is being used in other places already. I'm getting data-name using the id var dataName=document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("data-name");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`script_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) filter was introduced in WordPress 4.1:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'my_script_attributes', 10, 3 );

function my_script_attributes( $tag, $handle, $src )
{
    // change to the registered script handle, e. g. 'jquery'
    if ( 'MY_SCRIPT_HANDLE' === $handle ) {

        // add attributes of your choice
        $tag = '<script id="customID" data-name="customDataName" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '"></script>';
    }

    return $tag;
}
```